# I m citizen of India for transit should I need ATV

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, schengen-visas

I m travelling from India to Casablanca and I m booked ticket from Mumbai to Casablanca and my flight is mumbai Paris Paris to Rome and Rome to Casablanca should I need transit visa 
My layover is 4 hours

Comment: For this itinerary you need a regular Schengen visa, not a transit visa.